# Running SQL Server as a docker container. command line to start the container after system reboot

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have downloaded the SQL Server docker container onto my mac.

I downloaded the container using the following command from terminal

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

I was then able to run the container using the following command

```
docker run -e ‘ACCEPT_EULA=Y’ -e ‘SA_PASSWORD=MyStrongPassword’ -p 1433:1433 –name sql2019_latest -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

However I am finding that after taking my mac out of sleep/reboot, the image is always stopped

If I run

```
docker images
```

I get the following

```
REPOSITORY                                   TAG           IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server               2019-latest   80bdc8efc889   4 weeks ago    1.55GB
```

And when I run

docker ps

I then get nothing returned

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

I am trying to start the image, and I can start the image if I do it via the Docker Desktop, but I want to know what I should do to get the image started from a command line

I tried

```
docker run mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

and I get this in response

```
SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user mssql.
To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
The SQL Server End-User License Agreement (EULA) must be accepted before SQL
Server can start. The license terms for this product can be downloaded from
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746388.

You can accept the EULA by specifying the --accept-eula command line option,
setting the ACCEPT_EULA environment variable, or using the mssql-conf tool.
```

I then tried

```
docker run mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest --accept-eula
```

and I get this response:

```
SQL Server 2019 will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user mssql.
To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
/opt/mssql/bin/permissions_check.sh: line 59: exec: --: invalid option
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
```

What am I doing wrong to start my container from starting from the command line

*** UPDATE ****

Following the reply by Jamie F I did the following:

I ran the docker ps -a command

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                                       NAMES
cac05db1aac7   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   38 minutes ago   Exited (2) 38 minutes ago                                               agitated_cohen
0327940b7393   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   39 minutes ago   Exited (2) 39 minutes ago                                               focused_mclean
ad077064a63a   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   41 minutes ago   Exited (1) 41 minutes ago                                               objective_torvalds
c9809150f9d1   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   2 days ago       Exited (255) 44 hours ago   0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp, :::1433->1433/tcp   mssql2019
```

So I can see that there are 4 stopped containers, three with random names, but one with the name mssql2019

when I ran

```
docker start mssql2019
```

Then my image started

This is different from the name I thought I was giving the container, but in my instance I have been able to do what I required

I wanted to clean up the containers so I ran the following commands

```
docker rm cac05db1aac7
docker rm 0327940b7393
docker rm ad077064a63a
```

now when I run docker ps I can see my running image

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
c9809150f9d1   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   3 days ago   Up 4 minutes   0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp, :::1433->1433/tcp   mssql2019
```

and when I run docker ps -a I can see only one instance of the container

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
c9809150f9d1   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   3 days ago   Up 3 minutes   0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp, :::1433->1433/tcp   mssql2019
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first ran this container, you downloaded the image from the docker registry. Multiple instances of the container can be run from that image. `docker ps` shows running containers by default. You will see your stopped container if you run `docker ps -a`

To start a stopped container, you can run the command `docker start <container_name or ID>` so in your case:

`docker start sql2019_latest`

(See where you assigned that name when you first ran the container?)
`docker stop sql2019_latest` will stop it as well.

In your case, the container (sql2019_latest) and the container image (mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest) have very similar names. But that is not always the case. If you don't provide a name when you run the container, docker will create one for you, by combining a couple of odd words. Knowing when you are working with the image and when you are working with the container will help you a bunch.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have updated my original question to include what you have supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a [--restart](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart) parameter on the docker run command to restart the container after a reboot. The example below will automatically restart it unless it was stopped before the reboot.

```
docker run -e ‘ACCEPT_EULA=Y’ -e ‘SA_PASSWORD=MyStrongPassword’ -p 1433:1433 –name sql2019_latest -d --restart unless-stopped mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Comment: Thanks for this.